# Is this right for converting an infinite sum into an integral with the limit $[0; \infty]$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I've done the following to get from an infinite sum to an integral, the question is now, did i do everything properly and didn't made any mistakes, because i coulnd't find anything like that when searching for "how to convert inifinite sum to integral?"

$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(x_i) \Delta x
$$

while $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i = a + \Delta x * i$

when $b=\infty$ and $a = 0 \Rightarrow \Delta x = 1$ and $x_i = i$

$$
\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(i)
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is $\Delta x=1$? $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, which is an indeterminate form.

Comment: No - you need $\Delta x$ to approach $0$ at the very least.

Comment: But when i have $b=n$ and $a=0$, then isn't it $\Delta x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n}$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_of_limiting_operations

Comment: @Eric but how can $\Delta x $ approch 0 when i have these limits?

Comment: @octodino, $\Delta x$ *must* approach zero. The riemann integral is defined as the limit of the riemann sums as the partions gets finer. i.e, limit of the sum as $\Delta x\to0$.

Comment: Your definition (of the Riemann integral) from a to b is a valid definition. Now use that definition (which is already a certain limit) from a = 0 to b, and then let b → ∞ (a limit of a limit) to get the definition of the integral from 0 to ∞.